# Subsampling point cloud with PDAL

Tags: pdal

I have hundreds of LAZ files that I want to reproject and save in the folder named `reproject` with the following pipeline. It runs indefinitely but doesn't generate any output file.

```
json_pipeline = """
[
    {
      "type": "readers.las",
      "filename": "*.laz",
      "spatialreference": "EPSG:4326"
    },
    {
      "type":"filters.reprojection",
      "in_srs": "EPSG:4326",
      "out_srs": "EPSG:3857"
    },

    {
      "type": "writers.las",
      "scale_x": "0.0000001",
      "scale_y": "0.0000001",
      "scale_z": "0.001",
      "offset_x": "auto",
      "offset_y": "auto",
      "offset_z": "auto",
      "filename": "reproject/{originalfilename}"
    }
]
"""

import pdal
pipeline = pdal.Pipeline(json_pipeline)
count = pipeline.execute()
arrays = pipeline.arrays
metadata = pipeline.metadata
log = pipeline.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Python for this. Use the command line, Luke!

```
find . -name '*.laz' | xargs -I{} pdal translate \
      --input {} --output reproject/{} \
      --filter reprojection --filters.reprojection.out_srs="EPSG:3857" \
      --writers.las.offset_x="auto" \
      --writers.las.offset_y="auto" \
      --writers.las.offset_z="auto" \
      --writers.las.scale_x=0.01 \
      --writers.las.scale_y=0.01 \
      --writers.las.scale_z=0.001 \
      --writers.las.forward="all"
```

(Note that all of this should be on a single line or you must use line continuation `\` characters.)

The advantages of doing it this way are significant:

- It is going to run in parallel (use [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) if you want finer control over that or research how to use `xargs`)
- It isn't going to try to load all the data in memory (like your Python scenario above)
- A little more shell scripting could make it resilient resumable (test if the `reproject/{filename}` exists and don't do anything if so)

See the [PDAL Batch Processing Workshop Example](https://pdal.io/en/latest/workshop/generation/batch_processing/batch-processing.html) for more details or examples of how to use PowerShell to accomplish the same thing if you are on windows.